# Calculation of solar energy lack during Venus transit

Tags: planetary-transits

**The task**
The solar constant in Earth's orbit is $k$ ($k=1.37\text{ kW/m}^2$). Evaluate the solar energy lack due to the transit of Venus through the Sun diameter. Radius and orbit radius of Venus are $R_V$ and $r_{SV}$, respectively. Consider the orbits of Earth and Venus circular.
**My additional notation**
$R_\oplus$ is Earth's radius
$D_\odot$ is Sun diameter
$D_V$ is Venus diameter
$r_{SE}$ is distance from Sun to Earth
$r_{EV}$ is distance from Earth to Venus
$T_\oplus$ is orbital period of Earth
$T_V$ is orbital period of Venus
**My calculations**
The solar constant is $k=\displaystyle\frac{E}{St}$, where $E$ is the total solar energy, $S$ is sphere area of radius $1\text{ au}$, $t$ is time of solar energy radiation. Let $t$ be the time of Venus transit, then Earth gets energy $E=4\pi kR_\oplus^2t$ (without Venus). The Sun unit angular area gives $\displaystyle\frac{E}{\alpha_\odot^2}=W$ energy, where $\alpha_\odot^2$ is angular area of Sun. During Venus transit Earth gets solar energy $E'=W(\alpha_\odot^2-\alpha_V^2)$, where $\alpha_V^2$ is angular area of Venus. The energy lack is:
$\Delta E=E-E'=W\alpha_\odot^2-W(\alpha_\odot^2-\alpha_V^2)=W\alpha_V^2=E\left(\displaystyle\frac{\alpha_V}{\alpha_\odot}\right)^2=4\pi k\left(\displaystyle\frac{\alpha_V}{\alpha_\odot}\right)^2R_\oplus^2t$.
Then we have:
$\alpha_V=\displaystyle\frac{D_V}{r_{EV}}$;
$\alpha_\odot=\displaystyle\frac{ D_\odot}{r_{SE}}$;
$t=\displaystyle\frac{\alpha_\odot r_{EV}}{v_V-v_\oplus}$;
$v_V=\displaystyle\frac{2\pi r_{SV}}{T_V}$;
$v_\oplus=\displaystyle\frac{2\pi r_{SE}}{T_\oplus}$.
And substituting it all we obtain:
$\Delta E=\displaystyle\frac{kD_V^2R_\oplus^2r_{SE}}{2 D_\odot r_{EV}\left(\displaystyle\frac{r_{SV}}{T_V}-\frac{r_{SE}}{T_\oplus}\right)}$.
I'd like to clarify if this evaluation is correct.

And, I'm wondering how to use (type) astronomical symbols of planet here (if it's possible)?

Comment: I would hate to see Astronomy SE become a site for checking/doing homework.

Comment: Is there a reference to the "accepted" way to render the symbols for the planets on StackExchange sites?  Unicode / MathJax / other?

Comment: @ProfRob, thanks for the answer. I've read "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" in "Help center", and haven't found any reasons not to ask my question. I haven't written that my question is "homework". It's just a question regarding "Planetary Science and Celestial mechanics". I've described the problem and provided my reasoning with calculations. Maybe someone can help me to clarify this.

Comment: @misha.physics so a valid, but uninteresting, answer, that you would accept, is ",Yes this is correct"? Why do you think it might not be correct? Perhaps asking about whichever steps in your calculation are troubling you and why, would make a better question.

Comment: Another way to handle this would be to ask how to calculate the flux deficit and provide an answer yourself. Then you might get feedback on your answer.

Comment: @ProfRob, thanks. I think I just wanted to make sure my evaluating is correct, I would be glad to know if it's so. I built this solution by myself, but I'm not sure in some steps. Where I calculate the time of Venus transit, subtract orbital speeds, and consider the Earth's area like a circle area. Of course I would be grateful to know another way to calculate the flux deficit.

Comment: While you say $S$ is the area of a sphere with radius *$1\text{ au}$*, you write $S=4\pi R_\oplus^2$. But $R_\oplus=6378\text{ km}$ which is the Earth's radius. $1\text{ au}$ is the distance from Earth to Sun ($150,000,000\text{ km}$)

Comment: @SnackExchange, thank you, yes, I agree, it seems I was wrong about this problem.

Comment: @misha.physics And also, the $2$ should be in the numinator instead of denominator.

Comment: @SnackExchange, yes indeed. Thank you for noticing this.

Comment: @misha.physics :-)